# Mobile Heating Issues

Tags: gps, accelerometer, batterylevel, overheating

My Mobile Is heating up because of continues usage of my application .
For Detecting how well the driver is driving my application Uses These services :-

1. Accelerometer For starting the trip .
2. GPS To find the location and speed.
3. Then Syncing all the data to the server and writing that data to file locally.

After Few minutes my mobile heats up .
I Want to prioritize the services that is heating up my mobile and need to fix this issue of heating up .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the three apps you mentioned, GPS is by far the biggest power hog. It can be easily 50 times more than accelerometer. With GPS you are dealing with acquiring the signal in multiple frequencies, and it does a lot of number crunching at every specified epoch which also consumes a lot of power. However, for accelerometer the data is already inside of your mobile device. Thus, no significant power hogging for acquiring the data. I wouldn't worry about the 3rd case since a lot of apps do that with little heating problem.

So start with working on GPS case first.

Comment: To decrease battery usage i start fetching data at some intervals when user is driving a car and when car stops we stop fetching data and fetch data when accelerometer gives us some reading as we detect a car starts ....but still mobile heating issue is not as much resolved ....... any other way in which we can resolve this issue ?

Comment: I don't think stop fetching data can help much. Of course the GPS receiver can take a short break if you stop fetching data. But you lose connection to GPS satellites. When you start fetching again, the GPS receiver has to reacquire GPS data. That can take extra processing each time the receiver try to reacquire the data.

Comment: okay i will try the both and then i will compare the both cases....thanks @sung :)